# How to handle time values in Libre Office Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I need to record some stats, the relevant fields are a time value in format HH:MM:SS that needs to be converted in plain minutes:

[image]

I currently have two issues, the first I'm unable to show the leading 0 in the time value (named `tempo` in the image) the second issue is I'm unable to convert this time in simple minutes value to calculate average (`media`) and the corresponding time on a sample of 5 Km

I then would need to represent progression in a graph, showing for each entry the three values but this is another part of the story. I now tried to add the format to show the time with `:` rather than `.` but still I'm unable to add a leading 0 and the `minute()` function is returning an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LibreOffice, time and date values are stored as fractions of a day, so `1` means one day.  Formulas often rely on the fact that there are 24 hours in a day, 60 minutes in an hour, and 60 seconds in a minute.

After "Tempo" (in column C perhaps?), add another column called "Minuti" with the following formula to produce `62.6` minutes.  Format cells in the "Minuti" column as *Number (General)*.

```
=C2*24*60
```

Regarding leading zeroes, `HH:MM:SS` should show them.  For example, start with a new spreadsheet, enter `1:03`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and choose time format `HH:MM:SS`.  The result should show `01:03:00`.

Perhaps the problem is that the times are stored as strings rather than numbers.  In that case, you will need to convert the strings to time values first.

Comment: Many thanks! Main issue was having the hour with ' saved as string. I was able to show only `MM:SS` format for average times. Now I'm able to record my horrible jogging performances ;-) http://share.creoweb.it/e512a8fe.jpg